# Expression for 'One who likes expensive stuff, luxuries, but lacks appreciation?'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What would be an expression for:
Someone who wants expensive stuff; someone who wants luxuries, and who lacks in appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

***flashy***

see [flashiness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/flashiness)

> excessive or unnecessary display
>   *his penchant for flashiness, as evidenced by his expensive, specially tailored suits*

May be even ***vain***

see [vanity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vanity)

> Excessive pride in or admiration of one’s own appearance or achievements

Comment: This answer appears to be in formal violation of [the SE-wide policy on  referencing the works of others](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and of the [specific directions by our own moderator team](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981) from July 8, 2014. **You *must* include a simple plain-text attribution naming where you copied something from**, even a dictionary definition, or risk summary deletion because of unacceptably dangerous legal liability for unacknowledged copying, more commonly known as illegal plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[social climber](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/social-climber)*

> A person who is eager to gain a higher social status. Also called climber. [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Related terms are *[arriviste, nouveau-riche, parvenu, upstart](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/social+climber)* which generally mean

> a person who has suddenly risen to a higher economic status but has not gained social acceptance of others in that class [*The Free Dictionary.com*]

If the concept is of one who feigns sophistication or status, the term *[poser](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/poser#poser-2)* (or *[poseur](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/poseur)*) might apply

> A person who acts in an affected manner in order to impress others. [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Comment: Please note that the OP had mixed up the titles between this post and another. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are  referring to a 
[social climber](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/social+climber):

> - One who strives for acceptance in fashionable society.

Also a  [material](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Material) person can convey the idea:

> - Of or concerned with the physical as distinct from the intellectual or spiritual: "Great men are they who see that spiritual is stronger than any material force, that thoughts rule the world" (Ralph Waldo Emerson).

Source : www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Please note that the OP had mixed up the titles between this post and another. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

I would say such a person was *Spoiled*, as in spoiled child. Other good words:

> Grandiose, Narcissistic or Egocentric-regressed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a controversial choice, but I might use *affluenzal* in this situation. This would be the adjective form of the relatively new term for pathological materialism, [*affluenza*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affluenza).

This term officially denotes a real disorder, but its practical connotation often seems to be 'the condition of being spoiled as hell.'

Since *influenzal* is the adjective form of *influenza* (one of *affluenza*'s etymological parents), *affluenzal* would logically follow as the adjective form of *affluenza*.